# Why doesn't content wrap around floated image in IE7?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

See: http://hostingcouponsclub.com/codero-coupons.

When I click the `more<<`(above the red poll part) why under IE7 the content doesn't wrap around the image?

Under Firefox and Chrome, it's ok.

How do I make the content wrap around the image when click the red `more<<` text in IE7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when jQuery animates (your show/hide function uses "slow") it causes the animated elements to "gain layout" this is turn causes the text not to wrap : [**Reference**](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html#nextfloat)

e.g. your `pr_content` div lands up something like this with inline styles (in IE7, it's different in IE8)

`<div style="filter: ; zoom: 1; display: block" class="pr_content">`

There's various fixes but there's also various bugs, I tried a few different fixes like removing the filter but there's a also a bug with the removeAttr() function, I thought maybe removing the `style attribute` and using `.css()` to apply `display:block`  or `display: none;` might work but no joy, though YMMV

Here's your existing jQuery: (from idccoupon/scripts.js)

```
$('.pr_content').hide();
$('.moreteaser').click(function() { 
     $('.pr_teaser').hide();
     $('.pr_content').toggle("slow");
     $(".pr_content").attr("zoom","");
  $('.moreteaser, .lessteaser').toggle();
});

$('.lessteaser').click(function() { 
     $('.pr_content').toggle("slow");
     $('.pr_teaser').show();
     $('.moreteaser, .lessteaser').toggle();

});
```

Note: the `attr("zoom", "");` which I know is a recommended fix for this problem, is not working to remove the `zoom` property as far as I can tell.. which is what I found trying to remove other properties too.

I got it to half work  (i.e. no enhancement for IE) by removing the "slow" command for IE only, just means they get an instant show/hide rather than "smooth" one.. this or just letting IE users get unwrapped content like they have just now may be the easiest solution?

anyway here's the code I used in case you want to try it:

```
$('.pr_content, .lessteaser').hide();

$('.moreteaser, .lessteaser').click (function() { 
    if (jQuery.browser.msie) {
         $('.pr_content, .prteaser, .moreteaser, .lessteaser').toggle();
    } else {
         $('.pr_content, .prteaser, .moreteaser, .lessteaser').toggle("slow");
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because `<div id="provider_top">` is floated and `<div class="node-body">` (which is a sibling to the former) is not. Try putting `#provider-top` inside `#node-body` to see if that fixes it.

Comment: i put the <div id="provider_top"> in the <div class="node-body">,but it still can't work?